# change status value when date is less than current date

Tags: node.js, postgresql

in my table I saved a status field and expiration date, when the date is less than the current date I need to change the status value

One solution is to apply more job outside this is there another way? remembering that I need to change the status value in database

Comment: What is the "status" for an expired row?

Comment: the status has 7 values (1,2,3...) when it expires I want to set it to 2

Answer (score 0):

Either a view that overrides the status of expired and use that for queries instead of the base table:

```
create view mytableWithExpiry as
select
    col1, col2, ... 
    case when expiry > current_date then 2 else status end as status
from mytable
```

Or, periodically (daily, hourly, whatever) run this:

```
update mytable set
status = 2
where expiry > current_date
and status != 2
```